# Adding webParts on a Wiki page in SharePoint Online through CSOM and PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, powershell, csom, wiki-pages

I am trying to add a webPart on a SharePoint Online (Office 365) page using CSOM and PowerShell on a wiki page and that webPart always appears out of bounds like this:

[image]

Code:

```
    $xmlDocument = Get-Content -Path "C:\Users\<censored>\desktop\table_matieres.webpart" -Raw

    $wpManager = $page.GetLimitedWebPartManager([System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope]::Shared)
    $importWP = $wpManager.ImportWebPart($xmlDocument)

    $wp = $wpManager.AddWebPart($importWP.WebPart,0,0)
    $context.Load($wp)
    $context.ExecuteQuery()
```

Note: The table of contents is supposed to be on top of the site feed. The site layout got one top section and then one on the left and one on the right.

I am able, though, to remove webParts using the following code correctly:

```
    $list = $context.web.Lists.GetByTitle("Pages du site")
    $context.Load($list)
    $context.ExecuteQuery()
    $pages = $list.RootFolder.Files
    $context.Load($pages)
    $context.ExecuteQuery()
    $page = $list.RootFolder.Files | Where {$_.Name -eq "Accueil.aspx"}
    $context.Load($page)
    $context.ExecuteQuery()
    $wpm = $page.GetLimitedWebPartManager("Shared")
    $context.Load($wpm)
    $context.ExecuteQuery()
    $webParts = $wpm.WebParts
    $context.Load($webParts)
    $context.ExecuteQuery()

    $webPart = $webParts[0]
    $context.Load($webPart)
    $context.ExecuteQuery()
    $remove = $webPart.DeleteWebPart()
    $context.ExecuteQuery()
    $webPart = $webParts[2]
    $context.Load($webPart)
    $context.ExecuteQuery()
    $remove = $webPart.DeleteWebPart()
    $context.ExecuteQuery()`
```

After deleting (the startup webPart and the Documents webPart were removed from the top and the right section of the wiki zone correctly):

[image]

Is there a way to add the webPart directly in the correct zone through CSOM and PowerShell please?

Can you help me out with this one? This would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your time and your help.

Answer (score 2):

Wiki pages have a specific zone called "wpz" that you need to use.

Here's the code (in C#) from [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27268492/how-to-add-a-web-part-into-a-sitepages-home-aspx-using-csom),

```
public static void AddWebPartIntoWikiPage(ClientContext context, string pageUrl, string webPartXml)
{
        var page = context.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(pageUrl);
        var webPartManager = page.GetLimitedWebPartManager(PersonalizationScope.Shared);

        var importedWebPart = webPartManager.ImportWebPart(webPartXml);
        var webPart = webPartManager.AddWebPart(importedWebPart.WebPart, "wpz", 0);
        context.Load(webPart);
        context.ExecuteQuery();

        string marker = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "<div class=\"ms-rtestate-read ms-rte-wpbox\" contentEditable=\"false\"><div class=\"ms-rtestate-read {0}\" id=\"div_{0}\"></div><div style='display:none' id=\"vid_{0}\"></div></div>", webPart.Id);
        ListItem item = page.ListItemAllFields;
        context.Load(item);
        context.ExecuteQuery();
        item["PublishingPageContent"] = marker; 
        item.Update();
        context.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

**usage**

```
var webPartXml = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filePath);
using (var ctx = new ClientContext(webUri))
{
    AddWebPartIntoWikiPage(ctx, wikiPageUrl,webPartXml);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, sorry for the lack of updates, I have been busy working on several other projects.

I wanted to share my progression and what are the issues I am facing now.

I was able to "translate" the C# to PowerShell:

```
 $xmlDocument = Get-Content -Path "C:\Users\<censored>\desktop\table_matieres.webpart" -Raw

 $wpManager = $page.GetLimitedWebPartManager([System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope]::Shared)
 $importWP = $wpManager.ImportWebPart($xmlDocument)

 $wp = $wpManager.AddWebPart($importWP.WebPart,"wpz",0)
 $context.Load($wp)
 $context.ExecuteQuery()

 $props = $page.ListItemAllFields
 $context.load($props)
 $props["WikiField"] = "<div class=""ms-rtestate-read ms-rte-wpbox""><div class=""ms-rtestate-notify ms-rtegenerate-notify ms-rtestate-read " + $wp.Id + """ id=""div_"+ $wp.Id + """></div><div id=""vid_"+ $wp.Id + """ style=""display:block""></div></div>"
 $page.Update()
 $context.ExecuteQuery()
```

Although, now, the behavior is different and it does add the code to the ASPX page.

It seems to append the code even if there was already a wiki zone on the page (taken from SharePoint Designer):

```
 <SharePoint:EmbeddedFormField id="WikiField" FieldName="WikiField" ControlMode="Display" runat="server"><div class="ExternalClassA538D3FA9C374CD6B8B7E2F117F2C08D">
 <table id="layoutsTable" style="width&#58;100%;">
 <tbody>
 <tr style="vertical-align&#58;top;">
 <td colspan="2"><div class="ms-rte-layoutszone-outer" style="width&#58;100%;"><div class="ms-rte-layoutszone-inner" style="word-wrap&#58;break-word;margin&#58;0px;border&#58;0px;"><div class="ms-rtestate-read ms-rte-wpbox" ><div class="ms-rtestate-read 1aaac0d0-d055-4652-8be9-8880d2f16583" id="div_1aaac0d0-d055-4652-8be9-8880d2f16583"></div>
 <div class="ms-rtestate-read" id="vid_1aaac0d0-d055-4652-8be9-8880d2f16583" style="display&#58;none;"></div>
 </div>
 </div></div></td>
 </tr>
 <tr style="vertical-align&#58;top;">
 <td style="width&#58;49.95%;"><div class="ms-rte-layoutszone-outer" style="width&#58;100%;"><div class="ms-rte-layoutszone-inner" style="word-wrap&#58;break-word;margin&#58;0px;border&#58;0px;">
 <WpNs1:SiteFeedWebPart runat="server" __MarkupType="xmlmarkup" WebPart="true" __WebPartId="{0E290259-6B6D-4524-ACBC-4EBD6C93A6F3}" >
 <WebPart xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2">
 <Title>Flux de site</Title>
 <FrameType>None</FrameType>
 <Description>Le flux de site contient des conversations de microblog sur un site de groupe.</Description>
 <IsIncluded>true</IsIncluded>
 <ZoneID>wpz</ZoneID>
 <PartOrder>1</PartOrder>
 <FrameState>Normal</FrameState>
 <Height />
 <Width />
 <AllowRemove>true</AllowRemove>
 <AllowZoneChange>true</AllowZoneChange>
 <AllowMinimize>true</AllowMinimize>
 <AllowConnect>true</AllowConnect>
 <AllowEdit>true</AllowEdit>
 <AllowHide>true</AllowHide>
 <IsVisible>true</IsVisible>
 <DetailLink />
 <HelpLink />
 <HelpMode>Modeless</HelpMode>
 <Dir>Default</Dir>
 <PartImageSmall />
 <MissingAssembly>Impossible d'importer ce composant WebPart.</MissingAssembly>
 <PartImageLarge />
 <IsIncludedFilter />
 <ExportControlledProperties>true</ExportControlledProperties>
 <ConnectionID>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</ConnectionID>
 <ID>g_a2fc68fc_4cad_4acf_bca1_0d25a47e533f</ID>
 </WebPart>
 </WpNs1:SiteFeedWebPart>

 </div></div></td>
 <td class="ms-wiki-columnSpacing" style="width&#58;49.95%;"><div class="ms-rte-layoutszone-outer" style="width&#58;100%;"><div class="ms-rte-layoutszone-inner" style="word-wrap&#58;break-word;margin&#58;0px;border&#58;0px;"><div class="ms-rtestate-read ms-rte-wpbox" ><div class="ms-rtestate-read bf7102be-ad8c-4a20-83cb-5421f84c6e65" id="div_bf7102be-ad8c-4a20-83cb-5421f84c6e65"></div>
 <div class="ms-rtestate-read" id="vid_bf7102be-ad8c-4a20-83cb-5421f84c6e65" style="display&#58;none;"></div>
 </div>
 </div></div></td>
 </tr>
 </tbody>
 </table>
 <span id="layoutsData" style="display&#58;none;">true,false,2</span></div></SharePoint:EmbeddedFormField>
```

Note: Check after:

```
 </WpNs1:SiteFeedWebPart>
```

This results in the webpart being in an "invisible" zone.

The goal being to use a layout such as this:

[image]

I think it's called "2 columns and a header" in English.

I wanted to add a table of content webpart in the "top section", keep the "Site RSS feed" on the bottom left and have the bottom right empty.

Would there be a way to modify the ASPX page to achieve this goal please?

Thank you for your time and help again.